# git log, only commits that happened on branch pre-merge

Tags: git

If I have a structure like this.

```
    A---B---C----H---M      topic
   /       /  \     / \
  D----E---F---G---L---N    master
      /           /
 I---J           K          other topics
```

And I want to `git log`, only the commits that happened on the topic branch, without merges:
Specifically `A B H`, and nothing else.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the option `--no-merge` of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log --no-merges --first-parent topic
```

That is:

```
--no-merges
```

> Do not print commits with more than one parent.
>   This is exactly the same as `--max-parents=1`.

```
--first-parent
```

> Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. 
>   This option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge.